# How to keep all elements in bar chart when toggling between two datasets in d3? Quarter of initial data gets lost

Tags: reactjs, d3.js

I am new to implementing d3 with react. I am currently facing issues when toggling between two buttons to update my horizontal bar chart with data. My initial data has 63 records, whereas my second dataset has 27 records.
After toggling my second dataset to go back to the initial bar chart, almost a quarter of my records do not render in the page. Here is my component code. Any advice or suggestions are appreciated! Thank you!

**Here are screenshots of the process of which I write about in order:**

[Initial Bar Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktvWp.png)

[Toggle and Update Second Bar Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OycUM.png)

[Problem! A quarter of data in initial bar chart not rendering :(](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhVgM.png)

[Console log data between toggles and data appears to be there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLO5e.png)

```
export default function NYRepresenatives() {

    // SVG Ref Selector 
    const d3Container = useRef(null);

    // Toggle between assembly or senate
    const [barViz, setBarViz] = useState('assembly');

    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);


    //  -- - - -- - - - -- - -- - -- -- -- - -- -- - -- - -- -


    // Chart Dimensions
    const margin = {top: 10, right: 90, bottom: 10, left: 100};
    const width = 420 - margin.left - margin.right;
    const height = 800 - margin.top - margin.bottom;


    useEffect(() => {
        if(barViz == 'assembly') {
            d3.csv(aData).then(barGraph)

        } else if(barViz == 'senate') {
            d3.csv(sData).then(barGraph)
            
        }
    }, [barViz,loading])


    // Bar Chart
    const barGraph = (data) => {
        console.log(" data:", data);


        // Formatting the data
        data.forEach(d => {
            d.districtName = d.districtName;
            d.homesFlipped = +d.homesFlipped;
            d.memberName = d.memberName;
        })

        // Sorting data by Homes Flipped and saving to a new variable
        let sortedData = data.sort(function(a,b){
            return d3.descending(a.homesFlipped, b.homesFlipped);
        })


        // Maximum number in homes flipped 
        const max = d3.max(sortedData, d => d.homesFlipped);
        
        // Add X Axis widthScale
        const x = d3.scaleLinear()
            .domain([0, max])
            .range([0, width]);

        // Position of where the bar should be in the screen
        const y = d3.scaleBand()
            .range([0, height])
            .domain(sortedData.map(d =>  d.districtName))
            .padding(0.3);

        // Updating rects and text data 
        const u = d3.selectAll('rect').data(data)
        const t = d3.selectAll('text').data(data)


        // Container for Bar Chart
        const container = d3.select(d3Container.current)
            .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');
        

        // Selecting all the rects and joining it with our data, one rect for each member in our data
        let graph = container
            .selectAll('g')
            .data(sortedData)
            .enter()
            .append('g')
            .attr('class','groups');

        // Setting Bar Chart size 
        graph
        .append('rect')
        .merge(u) 
        .join('rect')
        .attr('fill', 'blue')
        .attr("width", 0)
        .attr('height', y.bandwidth())
        .attr('x',  0)
        .attr('y', d => y(d.districtName))
        .attr('class','bar')  
        .transition()
        .duration(200)
        .attr('width', d => x(d.homesFlipped))
        .attr('transform',`translate(${margin.left}, ${margin.top})`);

        // Tooltip Container
        const tooltip = d3.select(".tooltip__container")
        .style('position', 'absolute')
        .style('z-index', '10')
        .style('visibility', 'hidden')
        .style('padding', '10px')
        .style('border-radius','25pt')
        .style('background', 'rgba(235,95,42,0.8)')
        .style('color', 'white');

        d3.selectAll('rect')
        .on('mouseover', (e,d) => {
            d3.select(e.target).transition().attr('fill','#F5AA8F')
            tooltip
                .html(`<div>  ${d.homesFlipped} homes flipped in </br> ${d.memberName}'s District </div> `)
                .style('display', 'absolute')
                .style('visibility', 'visible')
                .style('top', e.pageY + 10 + 'px')
                .style('left', e.pageX + 10 + 'px')
        })
        .on('mouseout', (e) => {
        d3.select(e.target).transition().attr('fill','blue')
     
        });


    

        // Assembly Member Text
        graph.append('text')
            .merge(t) 
            .attr('x', function(d) { return x(d.homesFlipped) + margin.left + 20 })
            .attr('y', function(d) {return y(d.districtName ) + margin.top})
            .attr('fill','#0F26A6')
            .style("font-size", "10px")
            .style('font-weight','bold')
            .attr("dy", ".9em")
            .attr('class', 'mem__info')
            .text(function (d) {return  d.districtName }); 

            
        

        //exit
        u.exit()
        .transition()
        .duration(350)
        .remove();

        t.exit()
        .transition()
        .duration(350)
        .remove();

    }





  return (

    <section className="ny__reps">

        <div className='nyr__1'>
            <h1 id='nyr__head'>How many homes were flipped in your district? </h1> <br/><br/>
            <span id='nyr__subhead'>Homes flipped in NYC, 2017 - 2021 <br/>by State Legislative District </span>
        </div>


        <div className='nyr__2'>
            <div className='nyr__3'>
            <div className="ny__reps__btns">
                <button 
                    className="button"
                    id='btn-left'
                    onClick={() => setBarViz('assembly')}> 
                    Assembly Districts 
                </button>

                <button
                    className='button'
                    onClick={() => setBarViz('senate')}>
                    Senate Districts 
                </button>
            </div>
            <p id="ny__reps__note"> &nbsp; Click or hover over the chart to see the number of flips in each district &nbsp;</p>
            </div>
    
            <div className='tooltip__container'></div>

            <div className='nyr__4'>
                <svg className='vis__area' ref={d3Container}>
                </svg>
            
                {barViz == 'assembly' ? 
                    <img src={assemblyImg} className='img__map' />  : 
                    <img src={senateImg} className='img__map' /> }
             </div>
        </div>






    </section>
  )
}
```

I've tried searching online for folks with similar issues on merging and updating datasets for d3 charts. Have not found anything that has worked for my case.